# What if we display the retrieved data from XHR inside onload callback rather than asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript

I am beginner at JS and was learning AJAX(XHR object) and as you can see the code below. Also, guys if you won't get what I mean please let me know :-)

```
function easyHTTP() {
  this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

// Make an HTTP GET Request
easyHTTP.prototype.get = function(url, callback) {
  this.http.open('GET', url, true);

  let self = this;
  this.http.onload = function() {
    if(self.http.status === 200) {
      callback(null, self.http.responseText);
    } else {
      callback('Error: ' + self.http.status);
    }
  }

  this.http.send();
}

const http = new easyHTTP;

http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(err, posts) {
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
 } else {
     console.log(posts);
   }
 });
```

As you can see the above code uses asynchronous callbacks to handle the retrieved data and then console.log that retrieved data. But I wonder what if instead of using asynchronous callback we will handle the retrieved data and console log it inside onload callback like so:

```
let self = this;
  this.http.onload = function() {
    if(self.http.status === 200) {
      console.log(self.http.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log('Error: ' + self.http.status);
    }
  }
```

Then just use this code to execute it:

```
const http = new easyHTTP;

http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

I just cannot get what is the point of using asynchronous callbacks in XHR when we can wait and handle the retrieved data inside onload callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably following some tutorial or where did you get that code?

The reason for supplying a callback to http.get instead of adding the code directly to the onload method is easy: **Reusability**

What if you want to request from two different URLs and process the data differently? When you embed the processing code into the onload function, you have to implement different get-functions.

The callback on the other hand allows to request from different urls (or even the same) and handle the received data in different ways by specifying different callbacks. This is a typical generalization pattern in javascript.

By the way: The callback is not asynchronous. When onload calls callback, it is called directly, as if the code was at the same place. But what is asynchronous, is the http request itself. It starts executing, when the send method is called. After that javascript just continues executing code. After the request is completed the (anonymous) function assigned to onload is called.

Comment: yes I was following a tutorial. Thank you a lot for your help and explanation :)